# count number of disconnected sub-networks

Tags: r, igraph

In igraph is there a function that will return the number of sub-networks that are not connected to each other?

For example, it would return 3 for the network below.

Was pretty sure I had used a function like this in the past but can't find anything like it now. There are options for communities and for individual isolates but not for these disconnected sub-networks that I can find.

[image: example network]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `components`. For instance,

```
g <- sample_gnp(20, 1/20)
components(g)$no
# [1] 14
```

gives the number of them in `g`.